# Can't enter the BIOS after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, bios, grub-efi

I can not enter the BIOS after installing Ubuntu and for sure I do know my BIOS key is <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> for recovery. My laptop says it when it is opening.
When I try to enter the BIOS (<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd>, it doesn't matter) GNU GRUB menu, I only see Ubuntu and Advanced options for Ubuntu.

What I have tried is:
Exiting the GNU grub via the c or <kbd>ES</kbd> key on the command line for grub reboot, etc. It did not work.
I have physically removed the SSD on my laptop and then I couldn't get into the BIOS and it kept boot looping even though I have inserted a USB flash drive with Windows installation. It did not boot into it.
I tried to insert back the SSD and got into Ubuntu then within the terminal tried `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`. It did not work and it said my system does not support it somehow. Then I tried to physically remove the CMOS battery, and tried the top things while it was on the wall.

What I am sure of is;
I recently installed Ubuntu and to install it I needed to enter the BIOS via the <kbd>F2</kbd> key so I could change the priority of the bootloader to my USB stick. So I've had BIOS for sure.
I can open it to the system (Ubuntu) still.
My USB stick has proper OSs installed via Ventoy. I also tried other tools from within Ubuntu.

After all my tries, <kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't even send me to GNU grub. Instead it boots straight into Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry for the grammar and the bad sentencing I did not sleep for 30 hours trying figure things out of my laptop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `sudo dmidecode -t 0`